# ng-multiselect-dropdown custom css

Tags: html, css, angular

I am using the [**ng-multiselect-dropdown**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-multiselect-dropdown).  How can I override the CSS?

**component.html**

```
<ng-multiselect-dropdown [placeholder]="'Select Region'" 
    [data]="dropdownList" [(ngModel)]="selectedItems" 
    [settings]="dropdownSettings" (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)" 
    (onSelectAll)="onSelectAll($event)" > 
</ng-multiselect-dropdown>
```

**component.css**

```
    .multiselect-dropdown[_ngcontent-c5] .dropdown-btn[_ngcontent-c5] {
        display: inline-block;
        border: 1px solid #adadad;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 6px 12px;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: 400;
        line-height: 1.1;
        text-align: left;
        vertical-align: middle;
        cursor: pointer;
        background-image: none;
        border-radius: 4px;
   }
```

I need to override the default CSS with the above CSS code

Comment: you can add above css in your global style i.e style.css file with removing the angular default appended classes

Comment: to override global style  rule on the component style file, add this on your component `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,`

Comment: even by adding in the global style sheet it is not working @TheParam

Comment: i added encapsulation : ViewEncapsulation.None but still it is loading with its default css @JoelJoseph

Comment: also add `!important` to your component  styles

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Angular by default adds some `_ngcontent-xx` to your component CSS file so that it won't conflict with other components.

To solve your problem you need to add below CSS in your global **style.css** file or another way to make your component as `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` meaning its CSS won't append default classes of Angular.

**Solution 1**: Add in global stylesheet.

**style.css**

```
.multiselect-dropdown .dropdown-btn {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #adadad;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.1;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-image: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

**Solution 2** Make component `ViewEncapsulation.None`

**component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None // Add this line
})
export class AppComponent  {

}
```

**[Here is solution on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9w794r?file=src%2Fstyles.css)**

Hope this will help!

Comment: added the CSS in the global stylesheet but it is not working

Comment: in html i have only `<ng-multiselect-dropdown 
                              [placeholder]="'Select Region'"
                              [data]="dropdownList"
                              [(ngModel)]="selectedItems"
                              [settings]="dropdownSettings"
                              (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)"
                              (onSelectAll)="onSelectAll($event)"
                     >                               
                     </ng-multiselect-dropdown>`

Comment: You forgot .container in th start .container .multiselect-dropdown .dropdown-btn {

Answer (score 10):

You can try this way:

```
    :host ::ng-deep .multiselect-dropdown .dropdown-btn {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #adadad;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.1;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-image: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

you can override css of any node module or library by :host and ::ng-deep.

Comment: Best answer because it does'nt require to change global stylesheet or component.

Comment: Great Answer still works in 2023. I used it with ng-multi-select where I need to increase height of dropdown

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Surround your scss with `:host ::ng-deep` block like this:

```
:host ::ng-deep {
  .multiselect-dropdown {
    background: white
  }
}
```